# Batch File to Run Program for All Files in Directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a program that renames files and then moves them to another directory. This works great but I would like to automate the process using a batch script. I basically have a directory with video files (eg: test.avi or test.mkv). I want to open these files using the renaming tool (eg: rename.exe) and let it do it's thing.

How would I go about writing a batch script to achieve this? Ideally I would like to scan the directory on an hourly basis for files and then open them using the program.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the syntax of the renaming program?  Is it a command line tool or does it have a GUI?

Answer (score 0):

I use this to monitor if files are present in a folder , kinda opposite of what you want i check if the folder is empty.

You can make the minor changes to customise this , or we'll see if others have something better !!

Title=FileMonitor
@echo off
SETLOCAL

:LOOP
set VAR=0
for /F %%i in ('dir /b "c:\src*.*"') do set VAR=1
IF %VAR%==1 (
echo Folder has files at %time% >> 1.txt   ::###DO your thing here### 
GOTO :continue
)ELSE (
echo Folder is empty at %time% >> 1.txt
@echo
GOTO :continue
)

:continue
:: Sleep for 10 seconds ##Configure your time interval##
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10000 > NUL
GOTO :LOOP

GOTO :end

:end
ENDLOCAL